# Vowels not at the end or start of the words in string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the words in string not starting or ending with letters `'aıoueəiöü'`. But regex fails to find words when I use this code:

```
txt = "Nasa has fixed a problem with malfunctioning equipment on a new rocket designed to take astronauts to the Moon."

re.findall(r"\b[^aıoueəiöü]\w+[^aıoueəiöü]\b",txt)
```

Instead, it works fine when whitespace character `\s` is added in negation part:

```
re.findall(r"\b[^aıoueəiöü\s]\w+[^aıoueəiöü\s]\b",txt)
```

I cannot understand the issue in first example of code, why should I specify whitespace characters too?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `[^aıoueəiöü]` matches *any* char other than `a`, `ı`, `o`, `u`, `e`, `ə`, `i`, `ö` and `ü`. It can match a whitespace, a digit, punctuation, etc.

Also, you regex matches strings of at least three chars, you need to adjust it to match one and two char strings, too.

You do not have to rely on excluding whitespace from the pattern. Since you only want to match word chars other than vowels, add `\W` rather than `\s`:

```
\b[^\Waıoueəiöü](?:\w*[^\Waıoueəiöü])?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjDtZ3/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^\Waıoueəiöü]` - any word char except a letter from the `aıoueəiöü` set
- `(?:\w*[^\Waıoueəiöü])?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\w*` - any zero or more word chars
  - `[^\Waıoueəiöü]` - any word char except a letter from the `aıoueəiöü` set
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: thanks a lot ! can you suggest me good book for a bit deeper explanation of regex, material available online just scratches the surface

Comment: @azizalizada Check my YT channel, the link is on my SO profile page. However, the online materials are not that bad, check rexegg.com, for example.